# Display fields of a value and fields of its foreign keys psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm modelling a game in which every player has another player assigned to them who they must 'hunt'.

I have the following table in postgresql

```
    create table player( 
    id int primary key, 
    id_hunt int not null references player(id), 
    name varchar(30) not null, 
    email varchar(120) not null unique);
```

and would like to know how to display the name of every player and their id and the player who they must hunt and their id.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table player( 
    id int primary key, 
    id_hunt int references player(id), 
    name varchar(30) not null, 
    email varchar(120) not null unique); 
insert into player values (1, null , 'test', 'email');
insert into player values (3, 1 , 'test3', 'email_3');
update player  set id_hunt = 3 where id = 1;

select * from player ;
 id | id_hunt | name  |  email  
----+---------+-------+---------
  3 |       1 | test3 | email_3
  1 |       3 | test  | email


select pred.id, pred.name AS pred, prey.id, prey.name AS prey from player as pred join player as prey on pred.id_hunt = prey.id;

id | pred  | id | prey  
----+-------+----+-------
  3 | test3 |  1 | test
  1 | test  |  3 | test3
```

I changed `id_hunt` from `NOT NULL` so I could enter the first player. This is going to be an issue as you enter players for which there is no 'prey' yet.

At any rate the general idea is you do a self join by aliasing the table.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed and I feel like this will help me a lot as I learn!